# Getting Error: .... nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/Stri

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to run an Spring-Boot App, but it is giving me following error while running the application as a Java Application

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at main.java.start.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addServletMapping(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:290) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:215) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:178) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

My POM file is as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Web.Final.Project</groupId>
<artifactId>Web.Final.Project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>fitness365-group-project</name>
<description>Fitness 365 Web Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- <tomcat.version>9.0</tomcat.version> -->
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>WebFinalProject</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>org</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin> -->
    </plugins>

</build>
```

And my Java file is

```
package main.java.start;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class WebApplication {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
        }}
```

Please help, thanks in advance......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that you are using tomcat 9 instead of tomcat 8. In tomcat 8 the method `org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMapping` was [marked as deprecated](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html#addServletMapping(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

> Will be removed in Tomcat 9. Use addServletMappingDecoded(String, String)
>   Add a new servlet mapping, replacing any existing mapping for the specified pattern

Since `spring-boot-starter-web` 1.5.10.RELEASE is based on tomcat 8.5.27, it will not work if you run it with tomcat 9. The method that `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` want to invoke is gone. See the api doc of tomcat 9 [Context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html).

[image]

That causes the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

Try to find out if you are using tomcat 9. A `mvn dependency:tree` might help.

Comment: Thanks, I was using Tomcat 9, I changed it to 8.5 & it started working.

Answer (score 1):

You have two embedded containers in your web app. when you are using **spring-boot-starter-web** it has tomcat in it. and you can remove this dependency from your pom.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and then edit your **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency
like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

for more information, you can take a look at spring documentation
[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat)

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but I required Tomcat Server for my Application, hence I changed it to lower version(Tomcat 8.5.x) & it worked.